# What's the opposite of jQuery `.get()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.get()` converts a jQuery object to a DOM element that Javascript can use without jQuery.

If I have a DOM element, how can I convert it to a jQuery object?

Comment: Yes, you got the terminology right.

Comment: The opposite of `get` ought to be `set` ... right? :P

Comment: It's not really "converting" an object, it is more like *extracting* the underlying DOM element from the jQuery object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jQuery [core syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) accepts DOM elements: `$(theDomElement)`.

> `jQuery( element )`
>
> **element**       A DOM element to wrap in a jQuery object.

Recall that you're doing this every time you write `$(this)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var myDOMElement = document.getElementById("myDomId");

var myDOMElementConvertedTojQueryObject = $(myDOMElement);
```