# Transversing a JQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing sorting of a list of elements, using:

```
jQuery.fn.sort = function() {
   return this.pushStack( [].sort.apply( this, arguments ), []);
 };


$("ol li").sort("sortFunction").appendTo("ol");
```

The problem is in the sortFunction.

```
function sortFunction($a, $b) {
  ...
}
```

Basically, what I want is to treat both $a and $b as jQuery objects, so I can manipulate them.

e.g, inside the sortFunction do

```
$a.find("div#3 li").html();
```

This doesn't work since $a and $b are native javascript objects.

Any help?

Comment: I think you typod `("ol li".sort("sortFunction).appendTo("ol"));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DOM Element/Object to jQuery Element/Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974500/convert-dom-element-object-to-jquery-element-object)

Comment: Also someone else has already done this and written about it here:
http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are native DOM elements. You can call the jQuery function on one to wrap it, so that the jQuery functions are available:

```
$($a).find(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a native JS object into a jquery object like this:

```
var jsObject = $(nativeobject);
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply call jQuery on the objects?

```
function sortFunction($a, $b) {
   var jQueryA = $($a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just turn them into jQuery objects in the sort function:

```
$($a).find("div#3 li").html();
```

Note: don't call them `$a` but just `a`. Prefixing with the dollar sign generally indicates a jquery-type variable so it gets confusing if it is not